# Firestore function .where is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update data in a Cloud Firestore document, but I'm getting an error stating the .where() function isn't available on references, even though the documentation says it should be.

Code below:

```
deleteJob(e){
        //in Firebase, set "active" on job to N
        /**
        * The id of the job to delete will be bound to the element that calls it here
        **/

        let toInactivate = e.currentTarget.attributes[0].value;
        console.log(toInactivate);
        db.collection('jobs').doc().where("job_uuid", "==", toInactivate).update({
          "active": false
        })


}
```

Where db is the firestore reference variable.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not have the concept of update-queries. To update a set of documents, you will have to have a reference to each of those document and call `update` on each of them individually.

```
db.collection('jobs').where("job_uuid", "==", toInactivate).get().then(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => 
    doc.update({
      "active": false
    })
  })
})
```